# li and a:hover css

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to make simple list but have some problem. When i put some tekst in li element i want to set li width same like li text is..
And also I want when I hover over the li link, to change full li element background color,not just of A element..

This is my code..

```
#mid_left ul{ 
width:180px;

list-style:none; 
font-family:Verdana Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; 
}

#mid_left li {
width:auto;
background-color:red;
margin:10px 0;
padding:5px;


 }

#mid_left li a:hover{
background-color:blue;    
}
```

Example what i try to do is on page..(see footer)
http://buildinternet.com/2010/07/when-to-use-_session-vs-_cookie/

Comment: I don't mean any offense by asking, but is English a second language?

Comment: @Walkerneo: maybe Russian is the native language?

Answer (score 0):

Applies to the `a` element when you hover over the `li`.

```
#mid_left li:hover a{
    background-color:blue;    
}
```

Applies to the `li` element when you hover over it.

```
#mid_left li:hover{
    background-color:blue;   
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I was solve problem with li hover..Now i want to solve problem with width of li..I want to li have different width. If one  li element have more text i want to be bigger..like on the link..

Comment: then don't use a set width, give it a wrapper with a set width and set the li width to 'auto'

Comment: @user1252682, Then you can set the width inside the second selector

Comment: your code is absolutely right, just a note to add: the <a> needs to be inside the <li>....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Firebug to read their CSS?

```
#mid_left li:hover{
  background-color:blue;    
}
```

should take care of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle which (I believe) fits with what you're trying to do. Don't mind the colors, they're for illustration only.

http://jsfiddle.net/qwdd8/1/

edit: updated to remove inline-block, setting `width:auto`. I forced a height to the LI, but there may be better ways for keeping them from overlapping.

Comment: inline-block is not a supported display value in all browsers especially IE7-9

Comment: I didn't see the missing comma in the font family name. It doesn't change anything, but I thought I'd note it.

Comment: Mozilla has a nice article on supporting inline-block on older browsers here: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ Also, it's support is reasonably good, see:  http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block and http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html IE6 and IE7 are the only real concerns and the Moz article covers them.

Answer (score 0):

For the width-problem, don't set a width to the ul-element, so change:

```
#mid_left ul{ 
width:180px;

list-style:none; 
font-family:Verdana Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; 
}
```

to

```
#mid_left ul{ 
list-style:none; 
font-family:Verdana Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; 
}
```